# ¿Como podría inicializar a través de una clase externa los atributos de un objeto con la clase Scanner?

Tags: java

He creado tres clases, la clase Leer (Donde esta la clase `Scanner`), la clase **Main** y la clase **Fecha** (Con dos objetos f1 y f2).

Mi problema es que en la clase **Fecha** he declarado tres atributos enteros (año, mes y dia) con su respectivo constructor y metodos `get` y `set`.

En la clase **Leer**, no sabría como hacer para que la comunicación con la clase **Fecha** funcionara, es decir me gustaría introducir por teclado a través de un método los valores de los atributos de mis objetos con la clase `Scanner`.

**Clase Fecha**

```
public class Fecha {

    private int año;
    private int mes;
    private int dia;

    public Fecha(){

    }

    public int getAño() {

        return año;

    }

    public void setAño(int año) {

        this.año = año;

    }

    public int getMes() {

        return mes;

    }

    public void setMes(int mes) {

        this.mes = mes;

    }

    public int getDia() {

        return dia;

    }

    public void setDia(int dia) {

        this.dia = dia;

    }

    public boolean validarFecha() {

        boolean solucion = true;

        if(this.mes <=12) {

        switch(this.mes) {

        case 12: case 10: case 8: case 7: case 5: case 3: case 1:

            if(this.dia > 31) {

                solucion = false;

            }else {

                solucion = true;

            }

        break;

        case 2:

            if(this.dia >28) {

                solucion = false;

            }else {

                solucion = true;

            }

        break;

        case 11: case 9: case 6: case 4:

            if(this.dia >30) {

                solucion = false;

            }else {

                solucion = true;

            }

        break;


        }

        }else{

        solucion = false;   

        }

        return solucion;

    }

    public String toString() {

        String respuesta = "";

        if(validarFecha()==true) {

            respuesta = this.año + " " + this.mes + " " + this.dia;

        }else {

            respuesta = "La fecha es invalida";

        }

        return respuesta;

    }



}
```

**Clase Leer**

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Leer {



    public static Fecha readFecha() {

        Fecha fecha = new Fecha ();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);

         System.out.println("Dime un dia");
         int dia = sc.nextInt();

         System.out.println("Dime un mes");
         int mes = sc.nextInt();

         System.out.println("Dime un año");
         int año = sc.nextInt();

         return fecha;

    }


}
```

**Clase Main**

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Fecha f1 = new Fecha ();
        Fecha f2 = new Fecha ();

        System.out.println(f1.toString());

    }

}
```

Comment: por favor, añade el código de lo que llevas :)

Comment: Hola, @TALBARA solo usa los setter que defines en tu objeto. No olvides revisar [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio, saludos.

Answer (score 1):

En readFecha puedes hacer :

```
  fecha.setDia(sc.nextInt());
  fecha.setMes(sc.nextInt());
  fecha.setAño(sc.nextInt());
  return fecha;
```

y en main:

```
  Fecha f1 = Leer.readFecha();
  Fecha f2 = Leer.readFecha();
```

Lógicamente que tienes que agregarle validaciones. Espero te ayude.

Comment: Muchas gracias Guibovich

Comment: Si te resolvió el problema dala por aceptada.

Answer (score 1):

En realidad tu problema es que estas introduciendo los valores de día, mes y año pero no los estas asignado al objeto, para esto usa sus `setter` , agrega este cambio a tu método `readFecha()`, donde al obtener los valores, los asigna al objeto:

```
public static Fecha readFecha() {

     Fecha fecha = new Fecha ();
     Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);

     System.out.println("Dime un dia");
     int dia = sc.nextInt();
     fecha.setDia(dia); //* Agrega valor a objeto.

     System.out.println("Dime un mes");
     int mes = sc.nextInt();
     fecha.setMes(mes); //* Agrega valor a objeto.

     System.out.println("Dime un año");
     int año = sc.nextInt();
     fecha.setAño(año); //* Agrega valor a objeto.

     return fecha;

}
```

de esta forma ahora si podrías imprimir el valor de la fecha que introduces:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Fecha f1 = new Fecha ();
        Fecha f2 = new Fecha ();

        System.out.println(f1.toString());
        System.out.println(f2.toString());

    }

}
```